# Cookie is not being read by Edge or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, safari, microsoft-edge

I'm having a problem where my cookies are not being read by Safari or MS Edge. It works fine in all the other browsers just not in these 2. 
Has anyone come across a similar issue? If so how did you manage to sort it out? Thank you.

```
$('.primary-button.eligibility-button').mousedown(function() {

var selectedCard = $('input[name="cardInterestOption"]:checked').next().text();
var balanceTransferOption = $('input[name="balanceTransferOption"]:checked').next().text().replace(/[a-z]/g,'');
var annualIncome = parseFloat($( "input[name='annualIncome']").val());
var otherIncome = parseFloat($( "input[name='otherIncome']").val());
var totalIncome = annualIncome + otherIncome;
document.cookie = "creditCardSelectorEligibility=" + selectedCard + "; path=/;";
document.cookie = "creditCardBalanceTransfer=" + balanceTransferOption + "; path=/;";
document.cookie = "creditCardTotalIncome=" + totalIncome + "; path=/;";
```

});

```
(function() {
var page = "";
var percentage = "NA";
var path = location.pathname;
if(/results/.test(path)){
    page = "Success";
    var results = "";
    var percent = $(".results-banner:eq(0)").text();
    if(/\b[0-9]{2}/.test(percent)){
        results = percent.match(/\b[0-9]{2}/)[0]
    }
}
else if(/verify/.test(path)){
    page = "Verify";
}
else if(/problem/.test(path)){
    page = "Problem";
}
else if(/noteligible/.test(path)){
    page = "Not Eligible";
}
else if(/unavailable/.test(path)){
    page = "Unavailable";
}

var selectedCard = bt_cookie('yrd_creditCardSelectorEligibility')
var balanceTransferOption = bt_cookie('yrd_creditCardBalanceTransfer')
var totalIncome = bt_cookie('yrd_creditCardTotalIncome')

return page + "|" + selectedCard + "|" + balanceTransferOption + "|" + totalIncome + "|" + results;
```

})();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have found happen sometimes, is that the page loads too quick for the cookie to be created. So we have had to change the way the Cookies get created. For instance you can change the code to create the Cookie as the user interacts with the form. ie: If the select a button or fill in a field. Capture the cookie there, rather than at the end of the page where the customer has to click the submit. Hopefully this makes sense?